# Is cooked or uncooked rice offered in rudrabhishek? If so, which one?

Tags: shiva-lingam, puja

Is cooked or uncooked rice offered in rudrabhishek? If so, which one? Or is it both?

Comment: Both.. search on Google Anna Abhisekam (cooked rice bath).. uncooked rice (Akshata) is obviously offered.

Comment: You should include your question in the body too. Title itself is not the entire question. Body without question will be closed as unclear.